# Is there a way to download a complete Tumblr blog?

Tags: tumblr, download

Are there any tools that let me download an entire Tumblr blog? I'm not just looking for pictures and videos (I've seen tools for that) but also actual blog-posts (text)? Preferably there would be one tool to download everything (text, pictures, videos).

I don't know to what degree Tumblr uses other "external" (non-tumblr) services to host pictures and videos, but the program should be able to collect all content for a page/post, even if it spans to other hosts.

I'm looking to do this for any blog, not my own, so I have no special privileges. One in particular is about 10 pages.

I use mostly Linux, so a linux-tool or multi-platform (eg. java) would be preferable, though I can run Windows-programs too in a pinch.

Any suggestions would be welcome, even if it can't do everything at once. So suggestions for a good text-downloader, a good pix-downloader or a good vid-downloader are also very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with it you have a couple of options.

If you're wanting to copy it over to WordPress, you can use [Tumblr2WordPress](http://tumblr2wordpress.benapps.net/) to give you a standard WordPress XML file.

If you want the whole thing, posts & images, use [this Tumblr Backup](http://tumblr-backup.fugiman.com/) to give you a tarball including everything. A .TAR file is similar to a .ZIP file, and can be opened with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) if you're using Windows. It's python-based, and the developer even made the code [available online](https://github.com/Fugiman/Tumblr-Backup/) if you want to tweak it yourself!

Comment: Note: Fugiman’s backup tool doesn’t export post tags. (I don’t know if Baard Kopperud considers tags to be part of the post’s content, but others might.)

Answer (score 2):

Tumblr has an "Export" function, available at https://www.tumblr.com/settings/blog/, that will export all of your posts, including any pictures or videos. When you download the backup (after Tumblr creates it, which can take days), you get a separate HTML file for each post, with associated media in a separate folder, along with an XML file listing all your posts.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to do with this XML file, as my Web browser won't parse it.

Answer (score 1):

"[Backing up your Tumblr blog to Wordpress](http://quickguide.tumblr.com/post/39780378703/backing-up-your-tumblr-blog-to-wordpress)", a simple guide. It's very easy, all you really need to do is sign up for a free blog at Wordpress.com. The import practically does itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Frostbox](http://www.frostbox.com/). it works for videos, pics, text posts, quotes etc., and covers multiple blogs registered under one e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [LitchiSoft - Tumblr Photo Downloader](http://www.litchisoft.net/).  It's easier and more convenient to download photos and videos from Tumblr blogs.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the website dltumblr.com very useful in this regard since I am always looking for content to download from that website. Its quite helpful.

Comment: If this website does indeed solve the problem and answers the question - could you add a more detailed description on how to do it, maybe with some images or GIF, to improve the answer?